# F#:Block following this 'let' is unfinished. Expect an expression

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I know in F# we should [bind every single value to a name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055946/block-is-unfinished). 
And I think mine is ok???

But in the **if statement** I have the following error.

```
Block following this 'let' is unfinished. Expect an expression
```

and it comes from let  `min= List.nth list i`.
As far as I know I bounded the **min**  to  `List.nth list i`. So why it should be an error?

```
let mutable list =[-1;2;3;4]
let mutable min=list.[0]
let mutable i=1

if min<=0  then   let  min= List.nth list i
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to mutate a mutable variable, you can use the `<-` operator:

```
if min <= 0 then min <- List.nth list i
```

But this is not a very functional approach. A better method is to define a new value:

```
let minUpdated = if min <= 0 then List.nth list i else min
```